# How do I make the background of transparent Terminal windows blurry in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization

This is what gnome-terminal looks like currently:
[image: This is what it looks like currently]

I want the background of the terminal window to be **blurred**, roughly like so:
[image: This is roughly what I want]

Comment: You must improve your question. Do you wanna to turn your terminal windows transparent, is it?

Comment: Do you mean **opaque**?

Comment: edited, not looking for opaque, but something like aero from windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you want exactly. My answer doesn't meet your need, and so I'm going to delete it. I reckon you'll have to use some specific gtk+ themes to achieve your goal. A somewhat similar effect you can get by using [Windows Blur Effects](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/891/windows-blur-effects/) extension. It blurs everything but the active window(s).

Comment: The **Alpha Blur** option in the *Blur* plugin in Compiz should do the trick, but I couldn't make it work in my system. You can read about it here: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Blur

Comment: Just throwing this out there, konsole can be configured to have a blurred background, I am not sure if you need kwin for that effect though.

Answer (score 3):

sadly it's not currently possible, though efforts are being made to make it possible ATM. In the meantime, I think Ubuntu MATE with compiz can blur behind windows :)

To expand on this answer, KDE plasma now blurs beautifully behind windows and has a pretty cool theming system too :
[image]

Here's my desktop ! you can check out how I achieved it here : https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/8idl9p/plasma_shameless_macos_clone/